# Vector of struct with constructor

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have read a little bit about structs and vectors and I have ended up writing the following Node struct:

```
struct Node{
  float posx;
  float posy;
  int accessibility;

  Node() :
    posx(0.f), posy(0.f), accessibility(0) {}

  Node(float x, float y, int access) :
    posx(x), posy(y), accessibility(access) {}

};
```

Then in the main I want to create some instances of node and I use:

```
Node sampleNode(1.f, 1.f, 0);

std::vector<Node> graphNodes(N);
```

And they work fine, ok. But what if I want to create a vector of dimension N using the second constructor?? Because I've tried a couple of combinations (like *std::vector<(Node(1.f, 1.f, 0))>*,or *(graphNodes(1.f, 1.f, 0))(N)*, but didn't succeded. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any similar example elsewhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an [`std::vector` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) with a first parameter for the number of elements and a second for a value to which the elements are set:

```
std::vector<Node> graphNodes(N, Node(1.0f, 1.0f, 0));
```

This will create a size N vector full of copies of `Node(1.0f, 1.0f, 0)`.

Note that you can also pass an existing instance of `Node`:

```
std::vector<Node> graphNodes(N, sampleNode);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't "forward" the constructor arguments to the vector's constructor. Instead, do this:

```
std::vector<Node> graphNodes(N, Node(1.f, 1.f, 0));
```

The second argument to the vector's constructor is copied `N` times to populate the vector.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for

```
std::vector<Node> graphNodes(N, Node(1.f, 1.f, 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
std::vector<Node> graphNodes(N, sampleNode);
```